# Linking UNC Path on website

Tags: windows, samba

I am adding links to my organization's intranet page.  I have a SAMBA server that I would like users to be able to access from the intranet page.  Seems easy enough.  I created a link that works from macs "smb://ip/share" that works just fine.  For Windows users I added "file:////ip/share" and this works from Internet Explorer but most of our users on Windows are either on Firefox or Chrome.  Is there a way to get Firefox to open "file" links correctly? Or a better way for me to do my linking?

Comment: Don't forget to mark an accepted answer for this question.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Firefox [disables the file: handler](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Links_to_local_pages_don%27t_work), you could re-enable it in each browser.

Comment: +1 because on this web page are links to Firefox extensions which re-enable this file handler.